# exclude the folders - url rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

```
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(ajax|css|functions|image_viewer|images|img|include|fancybox|jquery|jscript|json)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.[^/])/(.[^/])/(.+[^/]) ?program=$1&usertype=$2&username=$3 [NC]
```

could you please help me find what is wrong in this.. ? I need to exclude some folders from url rewriting.

i tried with the solution given here.. but still i am getting some errors..

http://www.idxsync.com/sbaor/Search/Agent/zz

please help me

Comment: This has nothing to do with php and everything to do with mod_rewrite. Changed tags accordingly.

Comment: Please be more precise about what is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to have the following config:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:ajax|css|functions|image_viewer|images|img|include|fancybox|jquery|jscript|json) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ ?program=$1&usertype=$2&username=$3 [NC,L]
```